# Type of an Object Which Makes Function True

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript (v4.8), is there a way to enforce the following constraint: Throughout the codebase our library, our devs are introducing parameters that our end-users will specific in their own code. We would like a flexible way for developers to specify a validation function for acceptable values that the user could supply, as well as a default value in case they don't supply one. Some examples:

```js
const a = {validator: (n:number) => n > 10, default: 15}
const b = {validator: (s:string) => string.length < 5, default: 's'}
const c = {validator: (list: Array<number>) => list.pop() === 1, default = [1, 1]}
const d = {validator: (v: boolean) => v, default = true}
```

**I would like it to be a type error when the `default` makes the `validator` function return false.**

---

For context: I have a similar setup currently, where the options must be explicitly listed in an Array.

```js
type BaseConfigObject = string | boolean | number | object;

interface ConfigOption<F extends BaseConfigObject, D extends F> {
    possible_values: ReadonlyArray<F>;
    default: D;
}

export function checkedConfigOption<F extends BaseConfigObject, D extends F>(value: ConfigOption<F, D>) {
    return value;
}
```

Our devs then write things like:

```js
const terminal_settings = checkedConfigOption({ possible_values: [true, false, 'auto'], default: 'auto' });
const docked_settings = checkedConfigOption({ possible_values: [true, false, 'docked'], default: false });
```

This leads to a type error if the `default` is not a member of the `possible_values`. This is roughly the equivalent of having a validation function of `possible_values.includes(default)`.

My question is - **is there a way to cause a type error when `validator(default)` is false, for any function `validator` and value `default`**?

Comment: Extend how? It's not clear what the problem is.

Comment: Thank you @vr., I've clarified the question in a couple places.

Comment: So you want an error if `default` fails the validator function? I don't think that's possible...

Comment: This is not possible. In TypeScript's type system, the return type of non-generic non-overloaded functions like `(n:number) => n > 10` or `(s:string) => s.length < 5` is independent of its input.  The compiler only knows that they return `boolean` and has no idea which input values would make them return `false` in particular.  So it's pretty much a non-starter.  In very limited cases you could encode such information into the type system, but it would be much more trouble than it's worth. Does that fully address the question? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Please [edit] your code to be a [mre] with no typos; you should pass the code through an IDE to check before posting it here

Comment: Thank you @jcalz, that does answer my question - if you'd like to write up an answer, I'd gladly accept it. I'll fix the typos in the original question as well.

Comment: Okay I'll do so when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unfortunately impossible.  In TypeScript's type system, unless a function is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) or [overloaded](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads), the return type of the function is *independent* of the types of any of its parameters.  So inside

```
const a = { validator: (n: number) => n > 10, default: 15 }
const b = { validator: (s: string) => s.length < 5, default: 's' }
const c = { validator: (list: Array<number>) => list.pop() === 1, default: [1, 1] }
const d = { validator: (v: boolean) => v, default: true }
```

the `validator` properties are all functions that return `boolean` regardless of the input value.  And although `boolean` is equivalent to the [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `true | false`, that just means that every call to the function returns "either `true` or `false`".  TypeScript has no idea which input values return `true` and which ones return `false`.  It might seem obvious to a human developer how to determine that, but the compiler does not analyze function bodies by simulating their behavior for different hypothetical inputs; it would be unbelievably expensive to do so, and it would be impossible to compile almost any non-trivial program.  In some sense, you're expecting the compiler to actually *run* `x.validator(x.default)` *at compile time*, and that's just not how it works.

This is the job of runtime validation, not compile time validation, unfortunately.

---

I spent a little effort wondering how close you could get, though.  As mentioned above, the output type is independent of the input types, *unless the function is generic or overloaded*.

Overloaded functions are a dead end, because currently inference with overloaded functions only looks at the last call signature (see [ms/TS#43187](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43187) for more information).

Generics are *mostly* a dead end because abstracting over generics would require *higher kinded types* as described in [ms/TS#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213), and TypeScript doesn't have direct support for it.  You can kind of emulate support for it, so I used [`free-types`](https://github.com/geoffreytools/free-types) to try, and, well... it's bad:

```
import { Type, A, apply } from 'free-types'

type SplitStr<T extends string, A extends string[] = []> = T extends `${infer F}${infer R}` ? SplitStr<R, [...A, F]> : A;
type BValidator<T extends string> = "5" extends keyof SplitStr<T> ? false : true;

interface $BValidator extends Type<[string]> {
  type: BValidator<A<this>>
}

function bValidator<T extends string>(s: string): BValidator<T> {
  return s.length < 5 as any;
}

type Validator<$T extends Type<[any]>, V extends apply<$T, [V]> extends true ? any : never> = {
  validator: <U extends ($T extends Type<[infer T]> ? T : never) >(u: U) => apply<$T, [U]>,
  default: V
}

const asValidator = <$T extends Type<[any]>>(
  validator: <U extends ($T extends Type<[infer T]> ? T : never) >(
    u: U) => apply<$T, [U]>) =>
  <V extends ($T extends Type<[infer T]> ? T : never) & (
    apply<$T, [V]> extends true ? any : never)>(
      d: V): Validator<$T, V> => (
    { validator, default: d });

const bVal = asValidator<$BValidator>(bValidator);
const bGood = bVal("s"); // okay
// const bGood: Validator<$BValidator, "s">
bGood.validator(bGood.default); // okay
const bBad = bVal("oopsiedoodle") // error
// const bBad: Validator<$BValidator, never>
```

I managed to encode whether a string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) has less than five characters, and then encode `bValidator` as a generic function that performs this operation at the type level as well as at runtime... but the compiler cannot verify that equivalence so I needed a type assertion.

And then I can build up a validator using `asValidator(bValidator)`, but the compiler can't infer the higher-order generic so we need to specify it via `asValidator<$BValidator>(bValidator)`, and then after all that, we are allowed to initialize `b` with a default of `"s"` but not with a default of `"oopsiedoodle"`.

Blegggh.  So for each validator function you'd need to painstakingly try to represent the distinction between valid and invalid inputs at the type level, and then assert that the validator function actually does that, and then describe the higher order generic type that fits it, and... yuck, no thanks.

---

Instead compare to the equivalent runtime version:

```
interface Validator<T> {
  validator: (t: T) => boolean;
  default: T
}
const asValidator = <T,>(validator: (t: T) => boolean, def: T) => {
  if (!validator(def)) throw new Error("YOU MESSED UP!!");
  return { validator, default: def };
}
const bGood = 
  asValidator((s: string) => s.length < 5, "s"); // okay
const bBad = 
  asValidator((s: string) => s.length < 5, "oopsiedoodle"); // YOU MESSED UP!!
```

This is a million times better. So, in conclusion, this is the job of runtime validation, not compile time validation, unfortunately.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgFQJ5gKYBo4EEcCGYYANqnAL5wBmUEIcA5LRhgLQzoYDOjAUH06Y4AZVLAYImFAA8yOBgAeMDADsAJtzjdpwVQHMcuBcrWbtugwG0AunAC8cWwD4HKEyo1aABgBIEetQYUHAAYhT+gcFwAEoU3nAA-KLiktIyMThWAHS5+GE2rgBceADcglxwAEIAagQkwOoEMNByHmZaOlB6+q6OAEQArP3tXnAA1hioENQpDWmyyK7J1PXcGHAl0gCuGOV8eipQqwDGG7619Y3N0KPmaJgyVl09hYh8cHBCGCWXDU0tWS4GQwAAWwG4zmcfAoAmo21UJxgwAgqjgACM6v8bos7p1LL0ABTcEovAwASl+WOugLkrgQHzgUAwMG2UDR3GyJDU+jBcBkcEGcAIWgIqlQ5VhFWE1IBrV88iUnnuXCeYtQhRwNTxwuIZBkCqyNTeSo6XyguySwvFmzgqgwADdgn13p8HVc5VASjIAKo6wkKnUPDBPKIhZBvZLyEr2p1QclwZyE7YlH0J+yuIikVAG5BZH2axnqDCrbYkGAlGowgQnVE6YXcWU4ty5oOqqzqwpJxnu7GA71+01jAOK0xjYOh1RBcOR9wxx3BBPdz6fFNwNMOTN6nOGpwF5zp6GfGTaofmEdtx5WMMoWfRu0L+NwABkcEJjM+Wf1u6sxtcZ60HYNmSdVbVjRdlxXT51ErSk4CbWldxqPpXHfKCkF7GloBwYtS3LEp1Eocl9lrVR60xeo3BFBD5T+LCoCTCi+2gYi+FI8iAHEIAgQjHCYwl+m4fpiLgAB6US4AgcYCFQPhxLgdj4HRLieMrD0cQNOjPRwQT+mhZTuPUbJMM9QkDJ47JcIIMsYBE+SpJkti6yUqoCF4jEsQE7iwG4YAMHUQzuWEsSJOCOgoDkiTFIxVyYPg9TEK0nEcHAhiBFUAgQB4MACDOURQFIaIGU+Q5glODYaMWekPzgEycRKQkKxQQ8MW47kxXKKCrJskpkEZWFPmi6iEtuRw5CwJM6v7N8muQFr0TajAxRwktepa4qV2AWZCQAQim6BCVw8kEzBOgAHcHwugBRKBwoEgBNAB5P0AFkrpEEQroAEXXAAFHaduEzqV2ZVl2UQWqRqgFa8Ka3DKGBgaFOcjEVPc4bmKgQliVJAkWs5bkDD5AVBh0oS7IkhzZMGlH0ViqjGyh7GSQsboKU3bQuR5YnBR07zfP8wKMCBkK4Ce173s+n6fX+naBAoIA)